# Exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

Why get an error
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

code:

```
if (wynik[rozmiarMacierzy] == 0)
{
     for (int t = 0; t < rozmiarMacierzy; t++)
     {
            appendText(wynikiTextBox, wynik[t].ToString() + "\n");
     }
}
```

and

```
private void appendText(RichTextBox textBox, string text)
{
    textBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { textBox.Text += text; }));
}
```

Comment: what is `wynik` and `rozmiarMacierzy`? how you declared?

Answer (score 0):

add `wynik.Length >rozmiarMacierzy` condition like below

```
if (wynik.Length >rozmiarMacierzy &&  wynik[rozmiarMacierzy] == 0)
{
     for (int t = 0; t < rozmiarMacierzy; t++)
     {
            if( wynik[t]!=null)
              appendText(wynikiTextBox, wynik[t].ToString() + "\n");
     }
}
```